# (Python) converting a list of integers into tuples/sets changes positions of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, tuples

I want to convert

`E =[1,6,1,7,2,3,2,6,3,2,3,8,4,5,4,7,5,4,5,9,6,1,6,7,6,2,7,1,7,6,7,4,8,9,8,3,9,8,9,5,]`

into

`E = [{1,6},{1,7},{2,3},{2,6},{3,2},{3,8},{4,5},{4,7},{5,4},{5,9},{6,1},{6,7},{6,2},{7,1},{7,6},{7,4},{8,9},{8,3},{9,8},{9,5}`

but I get

`E=[[{1, 6}], [{1, 7}], [{2, 3}], [{2, 6}], [{2, 3}], [{8, 3}], [{4, 5}], [{4, 7}], [{4, 5}], [{9, 5}], [{1, 6}], [{6, 7}], [{2, 6}], [{1, 7}], [{6, 7}], [{4, 7}], [{8, 9}], [{8, 3}], [{8, 9}], [{9, 5}]]`

instead, and also the order in the sets {.} all get mixed up (order not preserved).

Why is this the case and how can I solve this?

My code is:

```
def convert_to_set(x):
    sets = []
    l = len(x)
    for i in range(0,l,2):
        set1 = []      
        set1.append({x[i],x[i+1]})
        sets.append(set1)
    return sets
```

Comment: `set`'s are unordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve order you'll need to switch from `set` to `tuple`.  It's easily done this way:

```
list(zip(E[::2], E[1::2]))
```

That gives you:

```
[(1, 6),
 (1, 7),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 6),
 (3, 2),
...
```

Comment: Great..What does this expr means `E[1::2]`?

Comment: @SauravSahu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll try to work a way around using a tuple instead of a set for the other portions of my code. :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is the following:

```
sets = [{E[i],E[i+1]} for i in range(0,len(E)-1,2)]
```

Moreover, sets are unordered so you cannot preserve the order.

Comment: OP main point is to preserve the order. So, your answer is not what he/she looking for.